# (Measure Theory) Can you help me understand this proof?

Tags: measure-theory

A function $f = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is defined on $[0, \infty)$.  Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\infty} f dx$ exists but $f$ is not integrable over $[0, 1)$.

Here is the proof posted by my professor:

[image]

I understand why this does not contradict the continuity of integration.  I'm confused by the absoulute value.  Why do we consider the limit of the integral of the function itself and then the limit of the integral of absolute value.  I looked through my notes and couldn't find anything similar.

What theorem is being used here to justify the proof?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about that too.  What you wrote definitely makes sense.

Comment: $f$ is defined on $[0,1)$ and then integrates on $[1,+\infty)$?

Comment: Bloody sores!  I meant to write $[0, \infty)$, doh!  I fixed it.

Comment: You needs to update the definition of $f_n$ also. If the integration region is $[1,\infty)$ then something like $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \chi_{[n,n+1)}(x) \frac{(-1)^k}{k}$ makes sense.

Comment: $f$ is Lebesgue integrable iff $f^+$ and $f^-$ are, then $|f|$ is. The second limit shows that is it not. Contradiction.

Comment: Please check your question. It makes absolutely no sense – in particular in comparison with  the proposed solution.

Comment: Yes, of course.  Btw, I'm about to drop out of school.